# How to connect to sharepoint 2010 cloud and read a list using groovy

Tags: grails, groovy, sharepoint-2010, groovyshell

I am not finding a way regarding how to connect to sharepoint 2010 cloud and read a list using groovy scrip .I googled a lot but did not find any clue.Kindly suggest me an idea or any resource how to do that? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What type of endpoint does sharepoint expose, web service, SOAP, REST?

Comment: @raffin : It is RESTservice so i am not finding any clue how to do that regarding how to connect to sharepoint cloud 2010 and pull the list details in the format of xml . please provide me any idea or resource .What is the best way to do that ?Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way to test in Groovy:

```
 String restUrl = "http://sharepoint/myrestendpoint"
 println( url.toURL().text)
```

Refer to this for a more formal approach:
http://groovy.codehaus.org/GroovyWS

Comment: where to give username and password and how to pull the contents in a sharepointlist please give me an idea .Thanks in advance

Comment: Follow instructions here: http://groovy.codehaus.org/modules/http-builder/doc/auth.html, hope it helps!

Comment: I tried the following code pull the particular list values in the form of XML @Grab(group='org.codehaus.groovy.modules.http-builder', module='http-builder', version='0.5.0-RC2' )
import groovyx.net.http.*
import static groovyx.net.http.ContentType.*
import static groovyx.net.http.Method.*
def authSite = new HTTPBuilder( 'mysharpoint.com' )
authSite.auth.basic 'username', 'password'
String restUrl = "mysharepoint/List"println( restUrl.toURL().text)println"success" but encountered with 403 error is this the right way what i am doing??

Comment: Try connecting to a website without authentication, to test groovy http builder; once that's working, then try with authentication. `403` means the server took the request but denied access to the resource.

Comment: How to try with out authentication @raffian??

Comment: You have to find one; run a web server on localhost or connect to yahoo.com, whatever, just use any URL without authentication.

Comment: yes it is working for sites without authentication but it is failing to pull the sharepoint list .It is showing 403 for the Specified List URL @raffian

Comment: Check for URL errors and make sure you're specifying an actual web page file name and extension, not just a directory. 403 means you're attempting to access a resource that's forbidden; authentication has nothing to do with it.

Comment: @Grab(group='org.codehaus.groovy.modules.http-builder', module='http-builder', version='0.5.0-RC2' )
import groovyx.net.http.*
import static groovyx.net.http.ContentType.*
import static groovyx.net.http.Method.*

def authSite = new HTTPBuilder( 'https://mysharepointwebsite' )
authSite.auth.basic 'username', 'password'
String restUrl="https://mysharepointwebsite/site/_vti_bin/listdata.svc/Listname"
println(restUrl.toURL().text) I am getting Forbidden error @restUrl@raffain but i am able to access it in browser